# Deep Learning for Arabic Natural Language Processing project

Tags: android, deep-learning, nlp, project, arabic

I'm about to propose a graduation project in Deep Learning for Arabic Natural Language Processing field. However, since I'm a beginner student **in this field**, I have already started learning a helpful [series of courses](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning), and I have almost a full year to work on this individual project. So, what are some great ideas for an Android application in DL for Arabic NLP?

P.S. I will gather the needed dataset if it's not available.

**Edit:** Recently, I read about [various problems](https://monkeylearn.com/blog/definitive-guide-natural-language-processing/) in this field, but most of them are very classic choices, and it seems to me that they don't give a good impression of my efforts while there exist many well-known and very efficient similar applications such as Google translate and Siri. However, Since my question is still too broad, kindly write down your suggested edits and recommendations.

Comment: Do you think that [Authorship Attribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry) is a possible choice in this case? (as a text classification problem)

Answer (score 1):

NLP is a broad area and have lots of application. And you will also need the supporting applications(web pages, editor, reviews in arabic). I will give some ideas and try order them easy to difficult.

1. Spell check
2. Sentiment analysis App - read reviews(movie/restaurant etc ) and rate them(provided you have data (sentence / +/- ))
3. FAQ from websites - given a question extract answers from FAQ of the website, we can NER to get organisation name and question similarity measure.
4. Grammar correction -  require lots of data(wrong - correct sentences) and editor app to use it in android.

Comment: Thank you for your suggested ideas, please read my edit.